# PHP Coding Help to create an array which references other array and the sum of items in the arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am struggling to create some PHP code for this and would appreciate your help. These arrays contain splits and laps of a person's run.

$laps shows that someone lapped their watch at 200m into their run and then 400m after that initial lap and then 600m after that lap etc...

$splits shows an automatic split which occurs every 1609m of the persons run. There is data ($splitGAP) which is directly related to $splits. So the first 1609m has GAP value of 0.5, the second 1609m has a GAP of -0.1 etc...

The sum of the distance in $laps equals the sum of the distance in $splits.

```
$laps = array(200,400,600,800,1600,800,600,400,200,836);
$splits = array(1609,1609,1609,1609);
$splitGAP= array(0.5,-0.1,0.7,-0.6);
```

What I want to do is create a $lapGAP array which is the size of $laps and has the correct GAP (with distance weighting) based on $split and $splitGAP.

For Example
200m + 400m + 600m = 1200m (first 3 entries of $lap). This is still within the first 1609m of $splits so the first 3 entries of $lapGAP should be 0.5.

So

```
$lapGap = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5...]
```

But the runner then goes 800m which spans the first and second entry of $splits. 409m of the 800m lap is associated with the first entry of $splitGap and 391m in the second entry of $splitGap.
(409/800)*(0.5)+(391/800)*(-0.1) = 0.20675

```
$lapGap = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.20675, ...]
```

Then the runner laps 1600m which spans the 2nd and 3rd entry of $splits. 1218m of the 1600m will be in the 2nd $splits and 382m in the 3rd $splits. Doing another distance weighted average
(1218/1600)*(-0.1)+(382/1600)*(0.7) = 0.09100

```
$lapGap = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.20675, 0.09100...]
```

And so on...

This does the job...not very efficient I suppose...

```
$laps = array(200,400,600,800,1600,800,600,400,200,836);
$splits = array(1609,1609,1609,1609.3);
$splitGAP= array(0.5,-0.1,0.7,-0.6);

$splitGAPperMeter = array_fill (0,round($splits[0]),$splitGAP[0]);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($splits)-1; $i++){
        $splitGAPperMeter = array_merge($splitGAPperMeter, array_fill (round($splits[$i])+1,round($splits[$i+1]),$splitGAP[$i+1]));
    }


    $sliceOfArray = array_slice($splitGAPperMeter,0,round($laps[0]));
    $lapGap[0] = array_sum($sliceOfArray)/count($sliceOfArray);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($laps)-1; $i++){
        $sliceOfArray = array_slice($splitGAPperMeter,round($laps[$i]),round($laps[$i+1]));
        $lapGap[$i+1] = array_sum($sliceOfArray)/count($sliceOfArray);
    }
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You should at least have some attempt to show us here.

Comment: Can a single lap value also cover _more_ than two splits?

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. I didn't want to confuse anyone with my attempt. I only got it to give me the first three entries...then couldn't' figure out the rest. A single lap cannot cover more than two splits

Comment: added an edit where I wrote something that does the job...not super efficient probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So under the conditions that each lap value can (partially) cover no more than two splits, and that the split distance is always the same, my approach would be this.

```
$laps = [200,400,600,800,1600,800,600,400,200,836];
$splitGAP = [0.5,-0.1,0.7,-0.6];
$splits = array(1609,1609,1609,1609);

$tempSum = $splitIndex = 0;
$result = [];

foreach($laps as $lap) {
  // if temporary sum plus current lap is below current threshold, add matching splitGAP value
  if($tempSum + $lap <= $splits[$splitIndex]) {
    $result[] = $splitGAP[$splitIndex];
    $tempSum += $lap;
  }
  // if temp sum plus current lap crosses threshold, split them up, calculate weighted result,
  // and move splitGAP index along by 1.
  // second reminder needs to become the new temporary sum
  else {
    $reminder_1 = $splits[$splitIndex] - $tempSum;
    $reminder_2 = $lap - $reminder_1;
    $result[] = $splitGAP[$splitIndex] * ($reminder_1 / $lap) +
                $splitGAP[$splitIndex+1] * ($reminder_2 / $lap);
    $splitIndex++;
    $tempSum = $reminder_2;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

This gives me the following result, please verify if the later values after 0.20675 still match what you expected here:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => float 0.5
  1 => float 0.5
  2 => float 0.5
  3 => float 0.20675
  4 => float 0.091
  5 => float 0.7
  6 => float 0.32516666666667
  7 => float -0.6
  8 => float -0.6
  9 => float -0.6
```

Comment: The values I am getting with your attempt you added to the question in the meantime, are slightly different. At index 4, I am getting `0.20337499999999` with yours, and `-0.09325` next, after that four more `0.5`. Since your explanation had 4 & 5 as `0.20675` and `0.09100` to begin with, I am assuming my version is “a bit more” correct here? Or is the result your own current code produces the one you actually need?

Comment: Wait, that’s not even correct, your version has _four_ `0.5` at the start, `0.20337499999999` only comes in 5th place (_index_ 4) - so your results also seem to be “moved” by one position. But then I am not sure if my _negative_ values at the end even make any sense.

Comment: hello, I actually think yours is more correct. thank you for the example